# Django inline formset with calculation and date using jquery

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-ui-datepicker, inline-formset

I have two models, it's a header/detail.

```
class Header(models.Model):  
   name = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=False)  

class Detail(models.Model):  
   header = models.ForeignKey(Header)  
   fromdate = models.DateField()  
   todate = models.DateField()  
   totaldays = models.IntegerField()
```

How can I put a datepicker in `fromdate` and `todate` using jQuery. Also how can I calculate days in `fromdate` and `todate`. If it's not inline formset, I can use a static datepicker but in inline formset it's not. Please do help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When the formset is rendered, the field's names are like `form-x-fieldname`, thus what I always do is to match against the field name. Try the "ends-with" selector ($=):

```
$('input[name$=fromdate],input[name$=todate]')
```